# Unable to use DropdownModule with ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

When trying to use both DropdownModule and ButtonsModule with the most current (1.1.14) version of ng2-bootstrap I get the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'DropdownModule' declared by the module
```

I had been using DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES and BUTTON_DIRECTIVES with a 1.0.24 version of ng2-bootstrap.  When trying to convert I can't even declare it in my NgModule without the error

Here is my module

```
import { DeviceService } from "./services/device.service";
import { DlSimpleFilterComponent } from "./dl-simple-filter/dl-simple-filter.component";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { TimepickerComponent} from "ng2-bootstrap";

//BDS Removed to get running
//import { DropdownModule, ButtonsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
//import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/dropdown';


@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        OperatorPipe,
        ConversationPipe,
        DlSimpleFilterComponent,
        DropdownModule,
//        ButtonsModule,
        TimepickerComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        OperatorService,
        ConversationService,
        DeviceService,
        DlSimpleFilterComponent
    ],
    bootstrap:    [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules should go in the `@NgModule.imports` not the `declarations`.

```
imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DropdownModule,
],
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  That was it.  Makes complete sense and is obvious to me now.